# How to make Hadoop Pig Job more reliable?

Tags: hadoop, error-handling, jobs

I have a pig job that's scheduled to run daily through the Hadoop Job Scheduler. It works perfectly at times, but fails sporadically with errors as below. Every day it reports a different reason for the failure.

Day 01:

```
Error: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
```

Day 02:

```
ENOENT: No such file or directory
```

Day 03:

```
Lost task tracker: tracker_bos-hadoop14.co.com:localhost/127.0.0.1:48865
```

Day 04:

```
Lost task tracker: tracker_bos-hadoop11.co.com:localhost/127.0.0.1:46408
```

Please suggest ways to make my job more reliable and resilient to such issues.

Are there any best practices to handle such hadoop failures?

Answer (score 0):

The first two are somewhat related - if you run out of disk space you can also get the second message from the task tracker when it is unable to chmod a task folder on the local disk (after an mkdir fails due to lack of space).

The second two you would need to check the task tracker logs in the node the TaskTracker runs on.

Without further context on what your pig job does, or how much data it processes (inputs and outputs) my guess would be to say that you probably need to expand your cluster (if you're running psuedo-distributed), or look at the distribution of you data in the shuffle stage - are the majority of your Key,Value pairs going to one single reducer, can you amend the number of reducers or your algorithm to reduce the amount of data being shuffled?)